# Unable to read data from GCS bucket using python inside a Docker

Tags: python, pandas, docker, google-cloud-platform, containers

Hello guys I am trying to read data from GCS bucket using python code inside a Docker image. It is taking unreasonably large amount of time for 1.23 gb csv file and the execution is getting killed automatically. I am attaching the Docker file and the python code.

```
FROM python:3.7.3

WORKDIR /Users/amansaurav/Downloads/xyz/data_process/
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install pandas --upgrade
RUN pip3 install sklearn
RUN pip3 install argparse
RUN pip3 install 'kfp' --quiet
RUN pip3 install pandas --upgrade
RUN pip3 install --upgrade oauth2client
RUN pip3 install gcsfs
RUN pip3 install https://storage.googleapis.com/ml-pipeline/release/0.1.20/kfp.tar.gz
RUN pip3 install "dask[complete]"

COPY . .
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS /Users/amansaurav/Downloads/xyz/data_process/key.json
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "./dataprep.py", "--path", "gs://bucketName/", "--filename", "test.csv" ]
```

Python code:

```
file_path = os.path.join(path,filename)
print('file_path: '+ file_path)

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='projectName')
with fs.open(file_path) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
print('done')
```

The code is stuck at the read csv part and the container gets killed after large CPU usage.
I have also tried to do it with pandas, but the result is same, container getting killed after high cpu usage:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

I am running this in my local docker env. Any leads on this will be helpful.

Edit 1 - I also tried this with a 200kb file and it was successful, but is failing with file size of 1.23 GB.

Comment: Could it be as simple as your container doesn't have enough memory to hold a pandas dataframe holding 1.23 GB of data at one time?

Comment: I have tried with 6GB memory to docker.

Comment: Can you share a bit more information regarding your container, it sounds that the issue lies in the resources needed for the tasks and not the code for what you mention on your edit